# Can I set is_rtl() to true?

Tags: multi-language, language

I am adding a section to my site in Pashto, which is a custom Arabic RTL language.

I can figure out how to inject "rtl" into the html tag and body tag using

```
add_filter('language_attributes', 'custom_rtl_dir_attr');
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_rtl_body_class');
```

... but because **is_rtl()** still returns false, things like the bootstrap rtl css don't get added automatically:

```
if (is_rtl())
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-rtl', "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css", array());
}
```

What I am really looking for is a way to SET **is_rtl()** to true, for these pages, so that WP treats them like a native RTL page.

Is there any way to set/override **is_rtl()** ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options:

1. In wp-config.php, set

   ```php
   $text_direction = "rtl";
   ```
2. If you've defined your own .po or .mo translation file for Pashto (is there really not one already?) there should be a string to translate

   - value: ltr
   - context: text direction

   Set the translation to be "rtl". If that's the user's loaded locale then that will be picked up automatically.